# Oracle 11g stuck at installation in oracle linux no error msg only showing | and stuck

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, error-log, centos-7

[image]

oracle not install on centos7 while installation it is stuck at 84% no error msg showing

Comment: Now which is it? Oracle Linux or CentOS? And the database version? 11.2.0.1?

Comment: centos 7 yes database version 11.2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for the 11.2 installer to throw an error on OL7/RHEL7 at the phase where the agent is being built. Based on your screenshot, that is where your installer was (Building Agent Libraries), but it was unable to display the dialog window for it. This can be fixed by editing `$ORACLE_HOME/sysman/lib/ins_emagent.mk`, and replacing:

`$(MK_EMAGENT_NMECTL)`

with:

`$(MK_EMAGENT_NMECTL) -lnnz11`

and finally clicking Retry. But the installer is unable to display the dialog on your system.

[Operating System Requirements](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/pre_install.htm#LADBI1106)

- CentOS is not a supported Linux distribution.
- Oracle Linux and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 are certified starting with 11.2.0.4.

If you have access only to database version 11.2.0.1, then use Oracle Linux 6 or Red hat Enterprise Linux 6.

Comment: should i install centos 6 ?? or any other open sours linux ?

Comment: @KIshorparmar CentOS is not supported. Oracle Linux is open source. Red Hat Enterprise Linux is open source.

Comment: Actually, the problem here is that the dialog is compressed to 1 pixel wide. It also happens with other dialogs during the installation. The link problem can be ignored (see Doc ID 1965691.1) and after installation you can install patch 19692824.